# Using databases across multiple computers - Ruby On Rails/MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, svn

I'm a bit new to web development so bear with me please. I have a Ruby on Rails project that I have configured to use with a certain database. However, multiple people are going to be working on this project (via SVN repositories), so I'm concerned that the database I'm using, along with all it's fields, won't transfer over when some other person checks out a copy. What exactly should I do to circumvent this problem? Do I need to host my database somewhere? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I might be missing something very simple, but why not use one central development database instead of a local copy on each machine? You'd just set the configuration to connect to it.

Comment: That would be nice, except I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: ah, well, ideally, your systems administrator would help you out with that. If not, you'll have to do some research on databases and see which one is best for your project. I'm a dev, but I've setup Postgres, MySQL, and Mongo using resources on the internet. That would be my suggestion :)

Comment: Hmm I will be sure to look into that then. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that every team member on the project will have their own version of the database. The best practice is to set up some test data that covers all of your developed cases in your `db/seeds.rb` file. That way, each developer can run that seeds file, and it will populate their particular database - whether they're on Mysql, Postgres, Sqlite, or something else. More importantly, that gives you the freedom to reset your database any time you need to, and still have test data to work with.

As far as fields go, those will be covered in your migrations - it's important to run `rake db:migrate` any time one of your fellow developers might have made a change to the database schema.